# Cloud Run high latency when invoked from Cloud Tasks

Tags: latency, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I'm experimenting with Cloud Run(fully managed) and Cloud Tasks and I have been seeing weird results in terms of latency.

I have a queue in Cloud Tasks that invokes an API in Cloud Run. The tasks are created with the following values:

```
{
     'http_request': {
          'http_method': 'GET',
          'url': 'https://<app>.run.app/<endpoint>'
     }
}
```

I have tried many queue configurations, same results.

Cloud Run is a python server that processes the request(nothing fancy) and returns a response.

The problem is that latency is so high (~15 min) for the requests coming from the queue however if I curl the endpoint `curl https://<app>.run.app/<endpoint>` it only takes a couple of seconds.

The 15 min. is the value I get for *Cloud Run's Request Latency* it does not include the delay in the queue.

I also found [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#latency-domains) in the known issues but it refers to *custom domains*, which I'm not using, so I'm not sure it is the same problem.

Has anyone faced(and hopefully solved ) something similar? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does the task complete successfully? Even after 15 minutes? Is your Cloud Run is deployed in publicly (allow unauthenticated mode)?

Comment: Tasks are processed successfully, just slow. Yes, it is on unauthenticated mode.

Comment: What is the configuration of your queue? Can you share a `gcloud tasks queues describe <your queue name>`?

Comment: As I mentioned I have tried many configs, current values are these `rateLimits:
  maxBurstSize: 5
  maxDispatchesPerSecond: 5.0
retryConfig:
  maxAttempts: -1
  maxBackoff: 60s
  maxDoublings: 2
  minBackoff: 1s
state: RUNNING`

Comment: Impossible to reproduce. Did you try to delete your queue and to create a new one?

Comment: If you can send your GCP project ID, Cloud Run service name/region, Cloud Tasks ID (or whatever else identifying info) to ahmetb at google, I can report internally. However if you have GCP support, please contact support as it's most likely something we cannot solve on Stackoverflow.